# Why can't override inherited class virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I've been trying to understand C++ inheritance and polymorphism a little bit better. But I'm having a really hard time getting this to work.

I have a base class called **Shape**.
I have **Rectangle** that is child of **Shape**. And **Square** that is child of **Rectangle**.

**Shape** has no **area**. **Rectangle** and **Square** have area equal to **width*height**.

Setting **width** and **height** for **Rectangle** is independent. In the case of **Square**, when setting **width** or **height**, the function will set both attributes to the same value. Unfortunately that is not what is happening if I try to use polymorphism by creating a **Square** on a **Rectangle**.

---

**shapes.hpp:**

```
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

// Base class
class Shape {
    public:
        virtual void setWidth(int w);
        virtual void setHeight(int h);
    protected:
        int width;
        int height;
};

// Derived class
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
      int getArea();
};

class Square: public Rectangle {
   public:
      void setWidth(int w) override;
      void setHeight(int h) override;
};

#endif /* SHAPES_H */
```

**shapes.cpp:**

```
#include "shapes.hpp"

// Base class
void Shape::setWidth(int w) {
    width = w;
}
void Shape::setHeight(int h) {
    height = h;
}

// Derived class
int Rectangle::getArea() { 
    return (width * height); 
}

// Overloading
void Square::setWidth(int w) {
    width = w;
    height = w;
}
void Square::setHeight(int h) {
    width = h;
    height = h;
}
```

**Testing the getArea() functions:**

```
    Shape rect = Rectangle();
    rect.setHeight(7);
    rect.setWidth(5);
    //I had to cast the Rectangle so it would be able to call getArea()
    cout << "Total rectangle area (w5xh7): " << ((Rectangle*)&rect)->getArea() << endl;
    Rectangle square = Square();
    square.setHeight(7);
    square.setWidth(5);
    //I would like to be able to call Square's getArea() without having to cast it.
    cout << "Total square area (w5xh7): " << square.getArea() << endl;
```

I had to cast the **Rectangle** so it would be able to call **getArea()**.
I would like to be able to call **Square's** **getArea()** without having to cast it. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Your design seems odd. Why shouldn't `Shape` have `getArea`? And why isn't `Rectangle` inheriting `setHeight` and `setWidth`?

Comment: `Shape rect = Rectangle();` -- you sliced your object. See the linked quesiton for more information. Any attempt to cast `rect` back to a `Rectangle`, as the shown code tries to do, will only result [in demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). C++ does not work this way. This is how objects might work in Java, but C++ is not Java.

Comment: Funny design that. "Area" is a `Shape` concept. Width and height are pertinent only to a rectangle, which should be directly inherited from Shape. "Length" is pertinent to a square which should, again be directly inherited from Shape. Doing it my way means you could introduce a Circle without messing up your existing code. Do you really need all those "setters"? Setter functions are for Java programmers who don't know what they are doing. Use a constructor and be done with it.

Comment: In geometry a square is a type of rectangle.  In object-oriented polymorphism, a square is not a rectangle, because a square violates a rectangle's contract for what it means to be a rectangle.  But as a learning exercise, you can ignore that for now.  (A concrete class deriving from a concrete class is a bit of a code smell anyway.)

Comment: The ideas behind the odd design is to make the exercise harder. It's a "what if" situation. That is the same reason for the setters. "What if a function ends up changing some attributes?". It doesn't need to be a setter, the same way we could be talking about other things other than shapes. This is just an exercise.

Comment: If attributes change then just rebuild the object.